# Multiple tables on single entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

We have an issue with our current doctrine setup.

We would like to map a unique entity to multiple generated tables. 
I know that's not a standard usage but our constraint necessitate some optimizations and we need to split our tables by account.

We tried to update the repository table name by calling *setPrimaryTable* on the classMetadata property before each queries. However, it seems that we can't update the table after the first execution.

Working example :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$productM = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:Product'); 
$classMetaData = $em->getClassMetadata('DataBundle:Product'); 
$classMetaData->setPrimaryTable(['name' => 'product_copy']); 
$productM->findAll(); // select * from product_copy;
```

Problematic case :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$productM = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:Product'); 
$classMetaData = $em->getClassMetadata('DataBundle:Product'); 

$productM->findAll(); // select * from product; 

$classMetaData->setPrimaryTable(['name' => 'product_copy']); 
$productM->findAll(); // select * from product;
```

Is there a proper solution to handle this case to be compliant with the doctrine philosophy? Is it at least possible?

We saw an other "solution" digging into the Gidmo code, using the AST walkers but that can only handle the select cases, not the other CRUD operations.

```
class FromWalker extends SqlWalker { 

    public function walkRangeVariableDeclaration($rangeVariableDeclaration) 
    { 
        $sql = parent::walkRangeVariableDeclaration($rangeVariableDeclaration); 
        // replace the table name by a custom one 
        return $sql; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `Mapped Superclasses`? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

You still need an entity for each table but this way you can prevent code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

after the first execution , maybe you can do `$em->clear()`, then it works.